# Issues with Sixaxis controller in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a PS3 controller. I love that blender has support for sixaxis controllers out of the box but when I create a python script to view the data, there is a bit of a problem.

When both joysticks are 100% in the same direction, (ie: X = -32767 for both joysticks) the right joystick goes back to 0. (Even though the right stick is at full tilt, it reads as 0) 0-99 reads fine, and 100 only reads wrong when the left stick is also at full tilt in the same direction.

In profiling software and in games, this in not an issue. I am 100% confident at this point that it is not an issue with my controller, but with the driver for PS3 controllers.

My question is this: **How can I direct blender to use the xbox 360 driver provided by my profiling software instead of the built in PS3 driver?**

For clarification, I typically use something called DS3. It's controller profiling software that provides support for PS3 controllers. It provides a driver that mimics a wireless 360 controller. I use this for games that don't support PS3 controllers.

Answer (score 1):

UpBGE fork of blender has much better controller support
Modern SDL2

It may solve your issue, while introducing you to many new capabilities.

Comment: well well well, whoever gives BluBrintRandom -1 should have the guts to debate the point, or is really ignorant of one of the people who has contributed the most to BGE and the continuous development of upbg and ketsji game engine

Comment: you should listen to the advice of BluePrint, there are very few who know as much of bge as BluePrint, I model in my own blender compilation, but my bge practices are in ketsji and upbge, because they do better things than the bge of the official branch of blender, even **Ton Roosendaal** can tell you [Ketsji Game Engine](https://github.com/bge-community/Ketsji-Game-Engine) | [UpBGE](https://upbge.org/)